# Lightbox with Swiper JS

Tags: swiper.js

I'm building a page where I'm using ACF Flexible Content to add a Swiper Slider.
Slider is built so far, but now I want to have a lightbox function in the slider.
For this I have the approach to duplicate the slider once (with one slide per view, instead of three slides per view). So far so good:
Now I want to click on e.g. a zoom icon on the second slider to get to the slide that was clicked on.
For this I have an ActiveIndex function, but I don't know exactly how to give the second slider the index of the first slider...

I have sketched this roughly in a pen:

https://codepen.io/webkonditorei/pen/JjLjRQW?fbclid=IwAR2NZWpzx30gqVWVDPdOkRVrTdMC637dLNPYvakUruFYOjr6auYaJw6L9tY

Or here the code:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container swiper1">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 1</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 2</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 3</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 4</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 5</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 6</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 7</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 8</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 9</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p onclick="umswipen()">Slide 10</p></div>
          
        </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination1"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev1"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next1"></div>
    </div>





    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container swiper2">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination2"></div>
      
 </div>

<style>
body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.sliderContainer {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>


<script>
<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
   slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 10,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination1',
    paginationClickable: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next1',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev1',
  },
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
   slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination2',
    paginationClickable: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next2',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev2',
  },
});


<!-- Get SlideIndex -->

function geSlideDataIndex(mainSlider){
            
    var mainSlider  = document.querySelector('swiper1');     
    var activeIndex = mainSlider.activeIndex;
    var slidesLen = mainSlider.slides.length;
    if(mainSlider.params.loop){
        switch(mainSlider.activeIndex){
            case 0:
                activeIndex = slidesLen-3;
                break;
            case slidesLen-1:
                activeIndex = 0;
                break;
            default:
                --activeIndex;
        }
    }
    return  activeIndex;
}

<!-- Scroll Second Slider to current Slide of first Slider on Click -->

function umswipen(activeIndex) {
    
swiper2.slideTo(activeIndex);
    
}
</script>
```

Here the second slider (which should be the lightbox) is of course visible, which it really should not be, but is just about the basic function

Ideas for an approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for some think lake: [LightGallery](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery).
This package can help you.